# elasticsearch - search query - ignore order

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using a query like

```
{bool: {must: [{match: {name: "Cat Dog"}}]
```

This gives me records with name e.g. "Cat Dog Cow" but not e.g. "Cat Cow Dog".

As I read here solutions for it can be used `span_near`, is this the only way?

I tried query such as :

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[],"must_not":[],"should":[{"span_near":{"slop":12,"in_order":false,"clauses":[{"span_term":{"name":"Cat"}},{"span_term":{"name":"Dog"}}]}}]}}}
```

But this gives me 0 hits. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) returns documents that match a provided text, the provided text is analyzed before matching.

**Adding a working example**

**Index mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "Cat Dog"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65230619",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.36464313,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Cat Dog Cow"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65230619",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.36464313,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Cat Cow Dog"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Search Query using span_near**

```
{
    "query": {
        "span_near" : {
            "clauses" : [
                { "span_term" : { "name" : "cat" } },
                { "span_term" : { "name" : "dog" } }
            ],
            "slop" : 12,
            "in_order" : false
        }
    }
}
```